# Is storing an API Key in Streamlit safe ? And how to safely store it

Tags: python, api, streamlit, secret-key

I want to create a Local Streamlit app (for UI porpuses), which only I will use i.e. this peice of code will not be given to anyone else

I have to access few Azure services using an API Key - which I am afraid to do because I don't know how secure Streamlit is.

Specifically speaking I am unsure whether storing the API Key anywhere in my python file can get "leaked" as I might unknowingly send data out (to streamlit).
By python file , I mean the one which I will run using `run streamlit python_file.py`

Apologies for asking such a basic question.

Note: I have read about [Streamlit Secret Management](https://blog.streamlit.io/secrets-in-sharing-apps/) , but still don't understand how storing the API Key as secret prevents Streamlit / Streamlit devs from accessing my secrets.

Comment: When you run a streamlit application locally (with `streamlit run` command), then the whole thing is evaluated locally and nothing leaves your computer. So, altough it is best practice to store such secret in an environment variable, and retrieve that within your python code, you can safely use said keys hard coded. Just be sure nobody has access to your code. I am definitely **not** recommending this approach, because altough right now you can maybe guarantee nobody has access to your source, this might change in the future (for example, when you check in your code in a source repository).

Comment: @JarroVGIT Thankyou, but a followup q: How can one be sure that the Streamlit modules that I have installed( pip install..) do not have a piece of code that sends my key to some other server